# Python 3 urllib HTTP Error 412: Precondition Failed

Tags: html, python-3.x, parsing, request, urllib

I'm trying to parse HTML data of a website. I wrote this code:

```
import urllib.request

def parse(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    strHTML = html.decode()
    return strHTML

website = "http://www.manarat.ac.bd/"
string = parse(website)
```

but it is showing this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\pupewekate\Videos\RAW\2.py", line 11, in 
>     string = parse(website)
>    File "C:\Users\pupewekate\Videos\RAW\2.py", line 5, in parse
>     response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
>   File
>     "C:\Users\pupewekate\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py",
>     line 223, in urlopen   return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>   File
>     "C:\Users\pupewekate\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py",
>     line 532, in open   response = meth(req, response)
>   File
>     "C:\Users\pupewekate\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py",
>     line 642, in http_response   'http', request, response, code, msg,
>     hdrs)
>   File
>     "C:\Users\pupewekate\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py",
>     line 570, in error   return > self._call_chain(*args)
>   File
>     "C:\Users\pupewekate\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py",
>     line 504, in _call_chain   result = func(*args)
>   File
>     "C:\Users\pupewekate\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py",
>     line 650, in http_error_default   raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code,
>     msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 412: Precondition
>     Failed

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website checks the user agent header. If it doesn't recognize its value it returns status code 412:

```
import requests

print(requests.get('http://www.manarat.ac.bd/'))
# <Response [412]>

print(requests.get('http://www.manarat.ac.bd/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome'}))
# <Response [200]>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24226797/1453822) for how to set user agent in urlib.

Answer (score 0):

You could use requests module as it is easier to implement, else if you are determined to use urllib, you can use this:

```
import urllib

def parse(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3;Win64;x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url,headers=headers)
    print response

website = "http://www.manarat.ac.bd/"
string = parse(website)
```