# Python - Pronote

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a french student and my high school have a website call Pronote use for write homework, if I'm present, etc... The problem: the site is often down, and it's impossible to recover the homework.

So, I wan't to create a Python script witch save sometimes a screenshot of the website. But he's coded in JavaScript and when I use python urllib2, Pronote return "Please use Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox...". So if you know how to do it, without open a windows, thanks for you're answer.

( I use Python 2.7, Windows 10 (x64), and I know the Pronote IP. )

Comment: I don't understand why you need urllib to take a screenshot. Since you're actively using the website anyway, your script just needs to take screenshots regularly.

Comment: But really, taking screenshots of code is a horrible solution for that problem. Your school needs to do something about that problem.

Comment: It's just for have a copy of the website when he's work, so my solution is to take a screenshot of the website, but a window will popup, and I use my PC for playing, so this is a bit embarrasing, or I can take a copy of the website code, but urllib don't work.

Comment: Pronote isn't only for my school, this is a universal tools for many of french school ( and probably more ), so it's just impossible to change the system of the tools, and there is no API, obsviously.

Comment: Sounds like you need to change the user-agent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226781/changing-user-agent-in-python-3-for-urrlib-request-urlopen

Answer (score 0):

You should try with the `pronotepy` module, it allows you to fetch homework and many other stuff using something like this:

```
import datetime
# initialise the client
# Note: the address should be a direct one (like the one below) usually the address shown by your school just redirects
# you to the real one.
# Ex.: https://your-school.com/pronote/students <-- BAD
#      https://0000000a.index-education.net/pronote/eleve.html <-- GOOD
#      https://0000000a.index-education.net/pronote/eleve.html?login=true <-- ONLY IF YOU HAVE AN ENT AND YOU KNOW YOUR IDS, ELSE REFER TO ENT PART OF README

try:
    client = pronotepy.Client('Your pronote URL',
                          username=input("What is your Pronote username?"),
                          password=input("What is your Pronote password?"))
    homework = client.homework(date_from=datetime.date(2022, 8, 28))
    files = {}
    urls = []
    for i in homework:
        for j in i.files:
            if j.type == 1:
                files[j.name] = j.url
            elif j.type == 0:
                urls.append(j.url)
        file = open("homework.txt", mode="a")
        file.write(f"Pour le {i.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y : ')} {i.subject.name} : {i.description} \n\n")
        file.close()
    print(files)
    print(urls)
except pronotepy.CryptoError:
    print("not logged in")
    input()  # the client has failed to log in

if not client.logged_in:
    print("not logged in")
    input()# the client has failed to log in
```