# urllib.request.urlretrieve got stuck when retrieved just one image from a site

Tags: python, python-3.x, special-characters, python-unicode

The python code (python3)

```
import time
import urllib.response, requests

from config.dev import CONTENT_IMAGE_UPLOAD

directory = CONTENT_IMAGE_UPLOAD + "en_" + time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
filename =  "sample.jpg"
try:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.miamiherald.com/latest-news/wfeh98/picture238148999/alternates/LANDSCAPE_1140/Screenshot%20(150).png", directory + "/" + filename)
    print("image is saved")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I am expecting to get the image in just less than one minute , but it take `too long` then print output as message like below.

`[Errno 60] Operation timed out`

I am sure the image is already exist because when I copied and pasted I got the image,
but it seem the URL contains some special char in this part `Screenshot%20(150).png`,

How could I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add user agent to bypass this issue, I never use urllib directly I usually use requests as it's easier for me, you can implement the same concept using urllib if you want, but you will need to look that up, here's a sample code

```
import time
import urllib.response, requests

# from config.dev import CONTENT_IMAGE_UPLOAD
headers = {"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"}
# directory = CONTENT_IMAGE_UPLOAD + "en_" + time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
filename =  "sample.jpg"
try:
    resp = requests.get("https://www.miamiherald.com/latest-news/wfeh98/picture238148999/alternates/LANDSCAPE_1140/Screenshot%20(150).png", headers=headers).content
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        f.write(resp)
    print("image is saved")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This might help you :)

[Changing User Agent in Python 3 for urrlib.request.urlopen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24226797/8692977)