# Getting error while web scraping the link

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-wrangling

Getting an error while scraping the link given. Can anybody please help me out with the error, And code for scraping web for the link to get all the text data.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
link='https://novelfull.com/warriors-promise/chapter-1.html'
req = Request(link) 
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you posted the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `requests`:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> res = requests.get("https://novelfull.com/warriors-promise/chapter-1.html")
>>> res.raise_for_status()
>>> res.text
'\r\n<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>...'
```

In order to get the *content* of the page (the actual story, in this case), you would likely need a web scraper, such as `BeautifulSoup4` or `lxml`.

### BeautifulSoup4

```py
import bs4
import requests

res = requests.get("https://novelfull.com/warriors-promise/chapter-1.html")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="html.parser")
elem = soup.select("#chapter-content div:nth-child(3) div")[0]
content = elem.getText()
```

`BeautifulSoup4` is a third-party module, so be sure to install it: `pip install BeautifulSoup4`.

### lxml

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml import etree

res = urlopen("https://novelfull.com/warriors-promise/chapter-1.html")
htmlparser = etree.HTMLparser()
tree = etree.parse(res, htmlparser)
elem = tree.xpath("//div[@id='chapter-content']//div[3]//div")
content = elem.text
```

`lxml` is a third-party module, so be sure to install it: `pip install lxml`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but neither of the both is woking. Both Beautifulsoup and lxml is showing error

Comment: @desktopp Did you install them? They are both third-party module, so you would have to run `pip install BeautifulSoup4` and `pip install lxml`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the user agent in the header as if calling from browser seems to work to avoid the `HTTP 403: Forbidden` error, e.g.:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
link='https://novelfull.com/warriors-promise/chapter-1.html'
req = Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
```

You can also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226781/changing-user-agent-in-python-3-for-urrlib-request-urlopen) for a similar case